# Android native codec packet loss, delay and bandwidth required

Tags: android, audio, packet, codec, bandwidth

I am going to implement a dynamic codec algorithm for VoIP,
the codec(s) i am using are what included in Android native library,
i.e.

- AMR   Adaptive Multi-Rate narrowband audio codec, also known as AMR or AMR-NB.
- GSM   GSM Full-Rate audio codec, also known as GSM-FR, GSM 06.10, GSM, or simply FR.
- GSM_EFR   GSM Enhanced Full-Rate audio codec, also known as GSM-EFR, GSM 06.60, or simply EFR.
- PCMA  G.711 a-law audio codec.
- PCMU  G.711 u-law audio codec.

(Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioCodec.html)

I would like to get their information about packet loss, packet delay or bandwidth usage (per direction), for making decision when changing codec during call. However, I can only find the information about G.711. For others, I can't find those information.

Is there any calculation for the data I required? I mean the packet loss, the delay or bandwidth, then I can decide which Codec to use when the network status of the device changes.